# NodeJs throws: Cannot post - error message

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I always receive the following error message from NodeJs when trying to get some content via a POST request. <-- This problem is solved.

I would like to get two fields from the database now: name and levels.

Here are the methods:

mongodb (courses):

```
_id: 12345
teacherId: 9876
userId: 567
name: "admin"
levels: "Advance"
```

route:

```
router.get('/course/:userid/showCourses', courseController.showCourseById)
```

controller:

```
const showCourseById = async (req, res, next)=>{
    try {
       let userId = req.params.userId || {};
       const course = await courseService.getCourseById(userId);
       res.json(course);
    } catch (error) {
       res.status(500).json({error: error})
    }
 }
```

service:

```
function courseService() {
    function getCourseById(userId) {
        try {
            await courseModel.findById({userId: new ObjectId(userId)}, 'name levels', function(err, items){
                if(err) return next(err);
                res.send(items);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Course not found. ${error}`)
        }
    }
    return {
        getCourseById: getCourseById
    }
}
```

And this is my Postman request

https://xyz/api/course/12345fabe3bd0a386d0962e77

Now, after changing router.post to router.get, I am able to call the method via Postman, however, it returns the login webpage

Comment: 1) GET method is appropriate for retrieving / querying data - POST is mostly used for create or update operations. (2) "let userId = req.params.userId || {};" - what are you trying to retrieve when userId is not provided (you need to be clear about this one)?

Comment: You are right. I I, incidentally, mixed that up. A userId is passed via GET request.